# Spring-jpa using spring-aop dynamic proxy?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, lazy-loading

I want know jpa "lazy loading". so, i tried debuging. but the first class that appeared was `JdkDynamicAopProxy.class`. and method was `invoke()`.

In the past, i read jpa book. but I could not read about it.

spring-jpa using Spring aop dynamic proxy?

I used spring boot version is '2.0.8' and 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'.

I tried debugging this code.

```
User user = userRepository.findById(595525L)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("does not exist user data"));
```

I found code to run `select` query.

```
final class JdkDynamicAopProxy implements AopProxy, InvocationHandler, Serializable {

...

@Override
@Nullable
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
  ....
  invocation = new ReflectiveMethodInvocation(proxy, target, method, args, targetClass, chain);
  retVal = invocation.proceed();  // here
  ....
}
```

Comment: This proxy has nothing to do with Spring Data JPA but with Spring Framework itself. But I don't understand what you ask. Are you looking for a tutorial like https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading?

Comment: thanks for comment. when you check the link that you uploaded, you can see "8. Conclusion".
"https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html" 

This link introduces `Dynamic Proxy Classes ...`